# Acrestar virgula no numero php

Tags: php

gostaria de acrescentar uma "," depois dos dois primeiros numeros. Por exemplo: 2098 -> 20,98;
20398 -> 20,398;
201 -> 20,1;
Alguem sabe como fazer isso em php?

Comment: `$numero / 10` deve suprir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
echo preg_replace('/^(..)/', '$1,', '2098'); // 20,98
```

Você pode ler mais sobre `preg_replace` [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php).

E expressões regulares [aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/expressoes-regulares-em-php/25076).

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda!